# Requests to Express app come with empty body though data being sent, but only in one route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, request

it's nice to join the group of people brave enough to ask the questions on Stack, so that everyone cantake advantage :)

My problem is pretty strange. I'm writing an app in Express, I have two routes so far and everything is going pretty smoothly, yet I've encountered one problem, which I can not seem to solve. In one route, with the patch method, the incoming requests have emmpty body. The rest of app is running smoothly, everything is working fine and this one route seems to be broken, I can not figure out why. Strange enough, yet I found out that the requests DO have body in one case - when I'm sending requests with my tests (supertest) using the .send({ ... }) method. When I'm sending requests with .attach or .field - they come empty. Same with requests sent from Postman (empty). What is causing such strange behavior?
Here are my tests:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const Image = require('../models/image');
const app = require('../app');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs')
const { setupImages } = require('./fixtures/db')

beforeEach(setupImages);

describe('[IMAGE] - ', () => {
    test('Should get images', async () => {
        const main_img = await Image.findOne({ main: true });

        const image = await request(app)
            .get(`/image/${main_img._id}`)
            .expect(200);

        expect(image.header['content-type']).toBe('image/png');
    });

    test('Should delete images', async () => {
        const image = await Image.findOne({ description: 'Lorem ipsum' });

        await request(app)
            .delete(`/image/${image._id}`);

        const imageFound = await Image.findById(image._id);
        expect(imageFound).toBeNull();
    });
    //TEST THAT FAILS
    test('Should edit images', async () => {
        const image = await Image.findOne({ main: false });

        await request(app)
            .patch(`/image/${image._id}`)
            .field('description', 'new desc')
            .attach('image', './src/tests/fixtures/imgtest.png')
            .expect(200);

        const returnChecksum = file => {
            return crypto
                .createHash('md5')
                .update(file, 'utf8')
                .digest('hex')
        }

        const imageEdited = await Image.findById(image._id);
        const newImageChecksum = returnChecksum(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/fixtures/imgtest.png'));
        expect(returnChecksum(imageEdited.image)).toBe(newImageChecksum);
        expect(imageEdited.description).toBe('new desc');
    });
})
```

Here are image routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();

const Image = require('../models/image');

const chalk = require('chalk');

router.get('/image/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        const image = await Image.findById(id);

        if (!image) {
            return res.status(404).send()
        }

        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
        res.send(image.image);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(chalk.red('Error serving image: ') + e);
        res.send(500);
    }

});
//THE ROUTE THAT FAILS
router.patch('/image/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const updateFields = Object.entries(req.body);
    console.log('image patch req body', req.body)
    try {
        const imageEdited = await Image.findById(id, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) { return err; }
            updateFields.forEach(field => doc[field[0]] = field[1])
            doc.save(res.status(200).send(doc));
        });
        if (!imageEdited) {
            res.status(400).send();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send();
        console.log(chalk.red('Error editing image: ') + e);
    }
});

router.delete('/image/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        await Image.findByIdAndDelete(id);
        res.status(200).send();
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send();
        console.log(chalk.red('Error deleting image: ') + e);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

And my app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
require('./db/mongoose');

const productRouter = require('./routers/product');
const imageRouter = require('./routers/image');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(productRouter);
app.use(imageRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

The result of console.log in image route:

```
  console.log src/routers/image.js:30
      image patch req body {}
```

And this is the behavior of the app with changed sending method in test:

```
test('Should edit images', async () => {
        const image = await Image.findOne({ main: false });

        await request(app)
            .patch(`/image/${image._id}`)
            // .field('description', 'new desc')
            // .attach('image', './src/tests/fixtures/imgtest.png')
            .send({description: 'new desc'})
            .expect(200);

        const returnChecksum = file => {
            return crypto
                .createHash('md5')
                .update(file, 'utf8')
                .digest('hex')
        }

        const imageEdited = await Image.findById(image._id);
        const newImageChecksum = returnChecksum(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/fixtures/imgtest.png'));
        expect(returnChecksum(imageEdited.image)).toBe(newImageChecksum);
        expect(imageEdited.description).toBe('new desc');
    });

    console.log src/routers/image.js:30
      image patch req body { description: 'new desc' }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it myself, the problem lied in fact that I've forgot about multer. So this strange behavior can be result of not using said library, even if you're not sending any files apparently.